# DELETE from Linked Server table using OPENQUERY and dynamic criteria

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, delete

I'm attempting to run a `DELETE` statement from my local SQL Server to delete appropriate records from a table in my remote linked server using `OPENQUERY()`. I'm using the following code, but it seems slow and I don't want to be pounding my server with bad SQL. Should I be using `OPENQUERY()` for this? Should I be deleting from it a different way that's more direct?

Here's my code:

```
DELETE RemoteTable
FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer,'SELECT * from RemoteTable_T1') AS RemoteTable
INNER JOIN MyDB.dbo.LocalTable_T1 AS LocalTable
ON LocalTable.LocalTable_T1_EntryID = RemoteTable.RemoteTable_T1_EntryID;
```

Any improvements I can make on this code since it is going to be set up as a recurring task on my server? I have about 5 different variations of this in order to delete from 5 different tables on my linked server.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, DML statements over Linked Servers is sllooowww (I believe that is the proper, technical spelling of this particular type of slowness ;-).

I found that the following setup was mucho faster:

1. Create a stored procedure on the remote server:

   - Call it something like `RemoteTable_DeleteByEntryIDList`
   - It should accept an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` parameter called `@EntryIDs`
   - The format of the data for that parameter will be a list of `EntryID`s in XML
   - The parameter cannot be of type XML as that is not valid for passing over a Linked Server
   - The proc will do something along the lines of:

     ```sql
     CREATE TABLE #TempIDs ([EntryID] INT NOT NULL);

     ;WITH cte AS
     (
         SELECT CONVERT(XML, @EntryIDs) AS [Data]
     )
     INSERT INTO #TempIDs ([EntryID])
       SELECT tmp.[EntryID]
       FROM   cte
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT tab.col.value('./EntryID[1]', 'INT') AS [EntryID]
                    FROM   cte.[Data].nodes('/row') tab(col)
                   ) tmp;

     -- optional: test to see if it helps or hurts
     -- ALTER TABLE #TempIDs
     --   ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_#TempIDs]
     --   PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EntryID ASC)
     --   WITH FILLFACTOR = 100;

     DELETE rt
     FROM   RemoteTable rt
     INNER JOIN #TempIDs tmp
             ON tmp.[EntryID] = rt.[EntryID];
     ```
2. Update your local stored proc to do something like:

   ```sql
   DECLARE @IDsToDelete NVARCHAR(MAX);

   SET @IDsToDelete = (
     SELECT EntryID
     FROM   dbo.LocalTable
     FOR XML RAW
   );

   EXEC [MyLinkedServer].[DatbaseName].[SchemaName].[RemoteTable_DeleteByEntryIDList]
        @EntryIDs = @IDsToDelete;
   ```